# Turkish tax exemptions for income from other countries?

Tags: taxes, tax-deductions, turkey

After about an hour of trying different search strings, I've read umpteen pages that all assume the person's income is from Turkish sources.  **[One](http://www.propertyturkeyforsale.com/is-my-pension-taxable-in-turkey-pensions-from-uk-eu-and-other-countries-g-16.html)** of them hints that a pension from another country is exempt.  None of them had anything to say about interest, social security, or capital gains from another country.  Nor static assets, i.e., the account balances and stock shares owned.

I don't live in Turkey now—I'm trying to estimate expenses if I move there.  **Is there a source a non-lawyer can consult on this?**  Not looking for info on IRS taxes—I'm already familiar with that.

I've been checking into a lot of countries and running into the same problem.  For reasons I don't understand, even pages about retiring in another country seem to have this problem.

Comment: Would you mind linking that "one of them"? Generally pension income is earned income, and is taxed as such. I've never heard of exempting pensions outright. There are tax treaty provisions that may be relevant, but that depends on the countries involved.

Comment: Actually, the USA/Spain tax treaty is about the same as USA/Turkey for pensions and Social Security.  The web page that said pensions are exempt may be incorrect.  But thought the treaty _allows_ them to tax the pensions, it's possible they may have chosen to waive that right.

Comment: The linked article talks about UK pensions, though, you're asking about US (I assume, since you've mentioned the IRS). Social Security is not a pension and is handled differently. I don't know if there's a totalization agreement between the US and Turkey in terms of benefits, but for tax purposes SS income is usually exempt by tax treaties.

Comment: To quote, "your UK (and other) pensions will not be taxed …"

Comment: I don't know what "other" pensions UK folks have, you should probably reach the writer to ask. But it was clearly written with the UK folks as the target audience, not US.

Comment: Easier said than done, but to me. "UK (and other)" sounds the same as "UK (and non-UK)"  That page and the tax treaty are the only things I could find that mentioned pensions.   And the tax treaty was the only thing I could find that mentioned anything else besides wages/salaries.

Answer (score 0):

Article 18, paragraph 1 of the [USA/Turkey tax treaty](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/turkey.pdf) seems to say the opposite of the [other web page](http://www.propertyturkeyforsale.com/is-my-pension-taxable-in-turkey-pensions-from-uk-eu-and-other-countries-g-16.html) I mentioned.  Article 18, paragraph 2 of the treaty seems to say that only USA can tax my Social Security.

Articles 10 & 11 say that both countries can tax the interest and dividends paid by institutions in USA.  But those articles have all sort of confusing limits and caveats and gobbledy-gook.

So, it looks like I **will** pay taxes to Turkey if I move there.  But how much, I'm not sure.  I did find [Turkey's 2020 tax rate schedule](https://www.expat.hsbc.com/expat-explorer/expat-guides/turkey/tax-in-turkey/), so I know *approximately* what I would pay if they tax *all* my income, i.e., I would pay something less than that but I don't know how much less.

Comment: Social security is not pension....

Comment: I know that.  As I said, pensions are in paragraph one and social security in paragraph two.